# After mouseup event, cursor turns back to default even though it's set to another icon. CSS, Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, cursor, mouse, default

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find why this is happening. I'm working on a Pixel art maker and I have a selection tool that selects table data in a table. After I click and drag the mouse to select the table data, on mouseup, even though the cursor is set to crosshair, it turns back to default cursor again. If I move the mouse even slightly on the table after that, it turns back to crosshair again. Needless to say, I do not want the mouse to turn back to default after releasing left-click. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Extra info:
Default cursor for the table is pointer.
After you click on the selection tool icon, the cursor for the table changes to crosshair.
Here is the javascript code for toggling the tool:

```
   //Toggle selection tool
  $(".tools").on('click', '#selectionTool', function () {
    if (tool == 'selection') {
      tool = 'pixel';
      $('#pixelCanvas').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    } else {
      tool = 'selection';
      $('#pixelCanvas').css('cursor', 'crosshair');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a fiddle?

Comment: @Phiter Problem seems to have solved itself once I restarted the browser and localhost :/ No idea why...